# "list" object have no attribute "lower"

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, object, lowercase

Can't figure out whats the problem,i wanted to make a program that takes a line of strings and return the words along with their type as decribed in the "In" function.

This is the code

```
def __init__(self):

    self.Action = "Action"
    self.Noun = "Noun"
    self.Shit = "Shit"
    self.Error = "Error"


    ACTION = ["Go","Kill","Jump"]
    NOUN = ["Lion","Building","World"]
    SHIT = ["shit","shit5"]






def Hard_worker(word):
    Action = "Action"
    Noun = "Noun"
    Shit = "Shit"
    Error = "Error"

    raw_data = word.lower()


    if raw_data in Action:
        return(Action,word)
    elif raw_data in Noun:
        return(Noun,word)
    elif raw_data in Shit:
        return(Shit,word)
    else:
        return(Error,word)

def scan(line):
    print"Scanning the line %r" % line

    words = line.split()
    return map(Hard_worker(words))


scan("Go Kill Jump")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should review the construction of a class and variable scope. Your \_\_init__ method is wasted. Also, case matters in variable names: Action, self.Action, and ACTION are all different variables and exist in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

```
return map(Hard_worker(words))
```

That's not how you call `map`. The function and the iterable must be two arguments.

```
return map(Hard_worker, words)
```

You can also use a list comprehension here.

```
return [Hard_worker(word) for word in words]
```